# How to create single platform for all the api gateways used for Rest API

Tags: architecture, cloud, api-gateway, apigee

I have a requirement to design a single platform to onboard all the API gateways which are being used by different teams within the project to manage the REST APIs. Now, the challenge here is that every API gateway will have its own way of providing security, for example, the Akamai gateway provides client secret & client-id to the consumer & consumer has to hit a separate URL in order to get the JWT security token which is being used to finally hit the actual API by sending the JWT token in the header. Similar way Apigee or KONG will have their own way of providing the security & it might happen that they only need an API key as a security token. Also, the gateway setup done for any REST API requires the whitelisting of IP addresses. How can I manage all this while developing a single platform portal & make sure that subscription or JWT token is floating seamlessly from the API gateway to our main platform portal... Basically, I'm looking for architecture & what software tools should I use to develop this. It will basically act as a mother portal that will internally connect with different API gateways & it will serve both the  REST API consumers & producers.

Comment: I can't say this is a classic problem with a well known classic solution. It really depends on the nature and culture of your organization, the capabilities of your team and involved peers, and your budget. I have though been in your shoes.

Answer (score 0):

Advice here, as this isn't an objective question with a particularly verifiable answer: First, work to standardize what is your organization's API-Management tooling. Are you a Kong shop, or an Apigee shop? If there is a standard, then optimizing your portal use-cases and integration requirements around that standard will be easier than the "many siloes" case. In any case, the key is to leverage the APIM stacks' management APIs to directly integrate. Apigee makes this easy via their long-term support for Drupal-based portals, in the form of their [Apigee Developer Portal Kickstart Drupal distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/apigee_devportal_kickstart)

Comment: Will 'API hub' of Apigee will make it easy to integrate with different API gateways like KONG or AKAMAI. Also for using the management APIs of different api gateways, do you think a good integrator tool like Snaplogic could ease the development & integration process. Also do you think 'connectors' of Apigee could help in the integration with different gateways

Comment: I do see Apigee API Hub playing a strong unifying registry-role among different API gateways like Kong and Akamai. SnapLogic (an iPaaS) could possibly assist, but better would be to drive your API-Mgt vendor consolidation... Apigee Connectors I see as more for bringing some management to your back-office's enterprise integrations (like with Workday or SAP), and probably less useful for coordinating among non-Apigee gateways.